# How to run PHP code inside Advanced Text Widget WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code which should return a list of posts in wordpress. I added this code inside the Advanced Text Widget which supports PHP but I can't get it to work.

```
<?php 
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'posts',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
)); 
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="pgsgrid">  
   <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 animated wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow- 
delay=".5s" data-wow-offset="5" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-name: 
fadeInUp;">
      <div class="hupjik">
      <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="pgs" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="medianews">
          <p><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
                             <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

           <p> <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" style="color:#ea6224">Read More &gt;</a></p>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What do you experience? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text widget doesn't support PHP code but you can able to run your PHP Codes using Shortcode.

Use this code to function.php for creating a shortcode:

```
function custom_post_widget(){
    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
    )); 
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="pgsgrid">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 animated wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow- delay=".5s" data-wow-offset="5" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                <div class="hupjik">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="pgs" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="medianews">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </p>

                        <p> <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" style="color:#ea6224">Read More &gt;</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_post_widget', 'custom_post_widget' );
```

Then use this code to your text widget: `[custom_post_widget]`
[image]

I tested and works.

Comment: Thanks. I had a typo as well in my code 'posts' instead of 'post' for post_type. Thanks.

Comment: How do you align the posts horizontally? Right now they are behaving like a list. Any CSS styling I could use? Thanks

Comment: Then you have to remove "col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-6" this classes. aslo remove "col-md-12" after that use any class where "col-md-12" was. then use this 
 css .col-md-12-replaced{ display:inline };